# I am trying to open a form and close the form behind it in Delphi 10

Tags: forms, delphi

I am trying to make a button open a form and close the form behind it (A log on screen opening the home page and disappearing once the home page is open). Everything I have tried has either opened both forms or closing the log on form has closed both forms. 
Current code:

```
begin
    frmHome.Show;
    frmLogOn.Visible:=false;
end
```

I have tried lots of variants of showmodal, close, closemodal to no avail. (If possible please can you explain the fix too as I am a student trying to learn the language)

Comment: Try    `frmHome.Show;     frmLogOn.Hide;`

Comment: Same problem occurs, it seems that hiding/closing frmLogOn closes the other form

Comment: Seems like frmLogOn is the main form chenge it & put frmHome as main form.

Comment: When you close the application's main form, it terminates the application.